# Export regression results as a csv file when using summary_out

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I am running multiple regressions using financial data from Yahoo! Finance and Fama-French factors from http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/f-f_factors.html

Single factor regression:

```
CAPM = sm.ols( formula = 'Exret ~ MKT', data=m).fit(cov_type='HAC',cov_kwds={'maxlags':1})
```

Three factor regression:

```
FF3 = sm.ols( formula = 'Exret ~ MKT + SMB + HML',     
data=m).fit(cov_type='HAC',cov_kwds={'maxlags':1})
```

I then utilise `summary_col` to create a table with significance stars:

```
dfoutput = summary_col([CAPM,FF3],stars=True,float_format='%0.4f',
model_names=['GOOG','GOOG'],info_dict={'N':lambda x: "{0:d}".format(int(x.nobs)),'Adjusted R2':lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x.rsquared_adj)}, regressor_order = ['Intercept', 'MKT', 'SMB', 'HML'])
```

**Output**

```
dfoutput
Out[311]: 
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary2.Summary'>
"""

=================================
             GOOG I       GOOG II  
---------------------------------
Intercept   -0.0009***   -0.0010***
            (0.0003)      (0.0003)  
MKT         0.0098***     0.0107*** 
            (0.0003)      (0.0003)  
SMB                      -0.0033***
                          (0.0006)  
HML                      -0.0063***
                          (0.0006)  
N              1930         1930      
Adjusted R2    0.37         0.42      
=================================
Standard errors in parentheses.
* p<.1, ** p<.05, ***p<.01
```

I have the following two questions:

1. Is it possible to change the standard errors in parentheses to t-stats?
2. Is it possible to export the results of the `summary_col` function to Excel as a `csv` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to change the standard errors in parentheses to t-statistics but only if you modify the file `summary2.py` in the `statsmodel` library.

You just need to replace the function `_col_params()` in that file with the following version:

```
def _col_params(result, float_format='%.4f', stars=True):
    '''Stack coefficients and standard errors in single column
    '''

    # Extract parameters
    res = summary_params(result)
    # Format float
    for col in res.columns[:3]:
        res[col] = res[col].apply(lambda x: float_format % x)
    # Std.Errors in parentheses
    res.ix[:, 2] = '(' + res.ix[:, 2] + ')'
    # Significance stars
    if stars:
        idx = res.ix[:, 3] < .1
        res.ix[idx, 0] = res.ix[idx, 0] + '*'
        idx = res.ix[:, 3] < .05
        res.ix[idx, 0] = res.ix[idx, 0] + '*'
        idx = res.ix[:, 3] < .01
        res.ix[idx, 0] = res.ix[idx, 0] + '*'
    # Stack Coefs and Std.Errors
    res = res.ix[:, [0,2]]
    res = res.stack()
    res = pd.DataFrame(res)
    res.columns = [str(result.model.endog_names)]
    return res
```

It is a good idea to comment out the original function (instead of deleting it) in order to be able to switch back and forth as necessary.

You can then do something along the following lines:

```
import pandas as pd        
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.iolib.summary2 import summary_col

df = pd.read_stata('http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/auto.dta')
df['cons'] = 1

Y = df['mpg']
X1 = df[['weight', 'cons']]
X2 = df[['weight', 'price', 'cons']]
X3 = df[['weight', 'price', 'length', 'cons']]
X4 = df[['weight', 'price', 'length', 'displacement', 'cons']]

reg1 = sm.OLS(Y, X1).fit()
reg2 = sm.OLS(Y, X2).fit()
reg3 = sm.OLS(Y, X3).fit()
reg4 = sm.OLS(Y, X4).fit()

results = summary_col([reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4],stars=True,float_format='%0.2f',
                  model_names=['Model\n(1)', 'Model\n(2)', 'Model\n(3)',  'Model\n(4)'],
                  info_dict={'N':lambda x: "{0:d}".format(int(x.nobs)),
                             'R2':lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x.rsquared)})
```

Evidently, the results now include the t-statistics instead of the standard errors:

```
print(results)

================================================
              Model    Model    Model    Model  
               (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)   
------------------------------------------------
cons         39.44*** 39.44*** 49.68*** 50.02***
             (24.44)  (24.32)  (7.85)   (7.80)  
displacement                            0.00    
                                        (0.44)  
length                         -0.10*   -0.09   
                               (-1.67)  (-1.63) 
price                 -0.00    -0.00    -0.00   
                      (-0.57)  (-1.03)  (-1.03) 
weight       -0.01*** -0.01*** -0.00*   -0.00*  
             (-11.60) (-9.42)  (-1.72)  (-1.67) 
N            74       74       74       74      
R2           0.65     0.65     0.67     0.67    
================================================
Standard errors in parentheses.
* p<.1, ** p<.05, ***p<.01
```

Note that you will manually have to change the text beneath the table to reflect the change, unless you are prepared to make further changes to the source code.

Once this step is complete, you can simply use the `as_text()` method to get everything in a string and export this to a text file using the `csv` library:

```
results_text = results.as_text()

import csv
resultFile = open("table.csv",'w')
resultFile.write(results_text)
resultFile.close()
```